# Stuck in a complex query

Tags: mysql, sql

Return the employees who have had at least 2 distinct orders where some product on the order had quantity >= 5

i have tried group by and having clause but not getting expected results. I have tried the following query and made some changes to it.

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.EmployeeName, COUNT(op.OrderId) AS orderCount 
FROM db_order.Employee e
JOIN db_order.orders o ON e.EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId
JOIN db_order.orderedproduct op ON op.OrderId = o.OrderId
WHERE op.quantity >= 5
GROUP BY o.OrderId
HAVING orderCount > 1
```

Output:
'E0002', 'E. Edwards', '2'

Expected Output:
E0006, D. Davis, 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select employeeid
from (select o.employeeid, o.OrderId
      from db_order.orders o join
           db_order.orderedproduct op 
           on op.OrderId = o.OrderId
      where op.quantity > 5
      group by o.employeeid, o.orderid
     ) o
group by employeeid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

I'll let you join in the employees table to get additional information.

EDIT:

You can also use your method with `COUNT(DISTINCT)` and the right `GROUP BY` keys:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.EmployeeName,
       COUNT(DISTINCT op.OrderId) AS orderCount 
FROM db_order.Employee e JOIN
     db_order.orders o
     ON e.EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId JOIN 
     db_order.orderedproduct op
     ON op.OrderId = o.OrderId
WHERE op.quantity >= 5
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.EmployeeName
HAVING orderCount > 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the employees having more than 2 orders with 5 or more items.

```
SELECT
    O.EmployeeId,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    OrderedProduct OP
    INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderId=OP.OrderId
WHERE
    OP.Quantity >= 5
GROUP BY
    O.EmployeeId
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 2
```